# I am having trouble with updating in kubuntu 15.04

Tags: updates, kubuntu, update-manager

I have recently started dual-booting Kubuntu 15.04 with Windows 8.1.

It worked well with the first round of updates but after adding repositories such as Wine and Playonlinux when I go to update manager and check for updates it says could not download packages.But when I click on details nothing comes up.

Also, when I run `sudo apt-get update` it works initially, but the is says `"waiting for headers"` then I get a bunch of 404's.

Comment: The PPA may not be available for Vivid Vervet. Remove them.

Comment: Thanks for responding, so how would one do this?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** The PPA may not be available for Vivid Vervet. Remove them.

---

To remove the PPA has several methods:

1. You can use the `--remove` flag, similar to how the PPA was added:

   Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

   Run it:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:{ppa_name}/ppa
   ```
2. You can use a safer alternative, install and run `ppa-purge`:

   Run it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update    
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge {ppa_name}
   ```

   With these commands you remove the PPA and downgrading packages it provided to packages provided by official repositories.

Comment: I have added your own comment in to your question to avoid confusion with your answer. :) And a +1